# firebase auth return null on signInWithPhoneNumber

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to login with phone number with firebase  signInWithPhoneNumber() method for login. In which i have checked whether user auth state has been change or not. If user auth is change then login and redirect to home page. but i m getting auth null

```
 onLoginBtnClicked() {

        const { contact, password } = this.props;
        const error =  Validator('password', password) ||  Validator('contact', contact);

        if (error !== null) {
          Alert.alert(error);
        } else {
              console.log('else');
            // this.props.loginUser({ contact, password});
            const mobileNo = '+91'+contact;
            firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(mobileNo)
            .then(data => console.log(data),
              firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
                console.log('user'+user);
                  if (user && !CurrentUser.isFirstTimeUser) {

                    const userRef = firebase.database().ref(`/users/`);

                    userRef.on("value", (snapshot) => {

                      console.log(snapshot.val());
                      snapshot.forEach(function(item) {
                        var itemVal = item.val();
                        if(itemVal.mobile == contact){
                                  NavigationService.navigate('Home');
                        }

                      });

                    }, (errorObject) => {
                      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
                    });
                    //NavigationService.navigate('Home');
                  }
                })
            )
            .catch(error => console(error.message) );


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to note here

- `onAuthStateChanged` is a listener which listen for the **user auth changes**.
- `signInWithPhoneNumber` sends the code to the user's phone, you have to **confirm** it to authenticate the user.

You need to add the listener in the react lifecycle for the component once it is mounted and remove it when it is unmounted

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ user: user.toJSON() });
      } else {
        // Reset the state since the user has been logged out
      }
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
     if (this.unsubscribe) this.unsubscribe();
  }

  // Send Message here
  firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(mobileNo)
     .then(confirmResult => this.setState({ confirmResult })
     .catch(error => // handle the error here)

  // Authenticate User typed Code here
  const { userCode, confirmResult } = this.state;
  if (confirmResult && userCode.length > 0) {
   confirmResult.confirm(codeInput)
    .then((user) => {
      // handle user confirmation here or in the listener
    })
    .catch(error => // handle the error here)
  }
```

Comment: what should be the flow if i wanted to login with phone number and setting up the auth state of currently logged in user? i dont want to send verification code to user every time he log in. i just simply want login feature which will redirect to home page successfully

Comment: Generally once the user signs in with the phone number, there is an onboarding step, in which you can ask the user to set `username, email,  password, confirm password`. If the user logs out / token expires and logs in again he should be able to login manually. If the user has not set up his onboarding , then this process is repeated again.